# Events sent by measurement protocol are not fully received and reported by GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to send some events from the backend of my website to GA. I've collected `client_id` from the client, and I send the `purchase` event using the following request:

```
POST /mp/collect?api_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&measurement_id=G-XXXXXXXX&measurement_id=G-XXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1

{
    "client_id": "1079763317.1697693644",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "purchase",
            "params": {
                "currency": "IRR",
                "transaction_id": "78248861",
                "value": "8792000",
                "coupon": null,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "item_name": "Item 1",
                        "price": "4396000",
                        "item_category": "ADL",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "item_variant": "Variant 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "item_name": "Item 1",
                        "price": "4396000",
                        "item_category": "ADL",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "item_variant": "Variant 2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The request is being accepted successfully with the code `204`. I have the log for all the requests and I'm sure that this request is being sent and accepted this way more than 7000 times daily.

But when I see the reports in GA, the count of this events are a lot less than what it should be, maybe about 800. It means that somehow a lot of these events are being missed.

Do you have any idea that what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

value and price values must be a number (without quotes).

transaction_id must be unique.

item_id is required.